# A question about commutativity of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ and $T$ be a linear operator defined on $V$. Then if $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are polynomials defined over $F$, then the the operators $P(T)$ and $Q(T)$ commute.

Is the converse true? i.e

> $AB=BA \implies \exists$ polynomials $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ over $F$ and a linear transformation $T$ such that:
>   $p(T)=A$ and $q(T)=B$

A hint in the right direction would suffice.

Comment: The answer is no in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Check this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563098/it-is-not-always-possible-to-express-two-diagonal-matrices-as-polynomials-of-som

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331960/81360) for the general case.